# How to sync data from embedded system to cloud through android

Tags: android, embedded, usb, cloud, synchronization

I have a small embedded system running Angstrom. It continuously generates a lot of data that I need to get to a MySql server in the cloud. I want to plug the USB port from the embedded system into the android, pull new data from the embedded system on to the phone, if the phone has a wifi connection than upload it to a cloud and if not then wait till it does have wifi and then upload.

Are there any tools/libs out there right now that preform this type of sync?

How about any tools to have the embedded system and android talk to each other? (there are some questions on here similar to that, but I thought I would reask it for my unique situation).

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data from the embedded system to the android device via USB then [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) is a good lightweight library for USB communication. An example of libusb used to implement a Linux based Android accessory can be found here: [android.serverbox.ch](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=262). This should at least get you started with passing the data to the android device.